# References of bitopological spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I'm looking for references about bitopological spaces. I've reading the book of Dvalishvili and the references therein, but I'm interested in the recent boundary research, more precisely the connection between bitopological spaces and related structures and non-commutative algebraic structures (if there is a such connection), or bitopological groups.

Comment: I have a paper "[Countably Compact Paratopological Groups](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00233-006-0637-y)" by Ofelia Alas and Manuel Sanchis. I guess its free version can be found in the Internet.